# How to add fonts in to scss in webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass

Here is my file structure.

```
 |- webpack.config.js
 |- index.html
    |- assets
       |- fonts
          |- .woff(s)
       |- images
          |- .jpg(s)
       |- js
          |- app.js
       |- scss
          |- app.scss
```

Here is my webpack.

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        __dirname + '/assets/js/app.js',
        __dirname + '/assets/scss/app.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/main.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [],
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: { outputPath: 'css/', name: '[name].min.css' }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: "assets/images/**/*"
                }
            ],
        }),
    ]
};
```

and
here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/app.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/dist/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here is my app.scss

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Futura Bold';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('../FuturaBT-BoldCondensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../FuturaBT-BoldCondensed.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Futura Medium';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('../FuturaBT-MediumCondensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../FuturaBT-MediumCondensed.woff') format('woff');
}
```

I got error "Cannot GET /dist/FuturaBT-MediumCondensed.woff2"

I also try with  `resolve-url-loader` add into .scss rules but i got another error.

can you please help me to add fonts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like your src urls are incorrect. Where do the files sit in relation to the dist? Would it maybe should be '`./fonts/Futura....woff'` instead? The error is just saying it's not finding the file in the path declared.

Comment: Hello @Chris W, I added file structure in my question.

Comment: Ok so should the path maybe actually be like `'./assets/fonts/Futura.......woff'`?

Comment: Sorry @ChrisW. can not get fonts on 'Cannot GET /dist/assets/fonts/FuturaBT-MediumCondensed.woff2'

Comment: remove `/dist/`, if anything just try the paths in the browser until you get a 200 successful and then you know your path. It looks like judging by your structure it would be `'../fonts/Futura..........woff'`

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW. it is work. I got font on  '/assets/fonts/FuturaBT-MediumCondensed.woff2'

Comment: Hello @ChrisW. /assests//fonts/Futura is access on server only. It is not work after build. and run it. because it is not copy into dist folder.